Как собрать libgdx проект на html?
Зашёл в установщик libgdx, в Supported Platforms выбрал только Android, но сейчас появилась необходимость собрать проект и в Html. Само собой, такой возможности нет, ибо поддерживает проект только андроид. Я могу как-то всунуть в проект возможность билда под html сейчас, после создания?
Если это важно - из Official Extensions у меня включены были FreeType, Box2D, Box2D Lights. Ниже картинка, как оно всё выбрано было изначально


Если коротко, то — нет, это разные технологии. Во времена существования апплетов такое вероятно можно было как-то осуществить, но времена те прошли (и возможно в будущем), а как это было можно посмотреть тут. Однако, Вы можете переписать все под HTML canvas, но вручную.

Но ведь в установщике есть галочка для подключения поддержки html. Если попытаться создать проект с box2d и freetype с поддержкой html - он создаст, но freetype работать не будет
Точно нельзя никак докачать поверх этот html?

Речь идет не о апплетах, а о преобразовании Java в JavaScript, посредством GWT. По сути, получится обыкновенное приложение на JavaScript.

Создайте еще один проект и просто скопируйте файлы из директории core, для вас это будет самое простое решение. Если делали какие-то правки вне core, то и их тоже (например, ассеты). Но, хочу предупредить, что то что они называют HTML, по сути будет использоваться GWT, что не позволяет один-к-одному преобразовывать Java -> JavaScript и возможно что код придется адаптировать.
